# How to call a variable in a for loop c++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

Im trying to call a variable declared at the start of the program in a for loop, but every time do it the loop runs forever, when i replace the varaible with a number it works fine, why is it doing this and how can i fix it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int array[] = {};
    int dec; //user input
    int v = 1; //other variable
    int co = 0; //This is the varaible i want to call

    cout << "Input here : ";
    cin >> dec;
    cout << "\n\n";

    while (v <= dec) {
        co++; //this were i assing the variable
        v = v * 2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i != co; i++) { //this is where i have the problem, i cant call `co`
        co = co - 1;
        if (v <= dec) { //Binary will be 1
            dec = dec - v;
            v = v / 2;
            array[i] = 1;
        }
        else { //Binary will be 0
            v = v / 2;
            array[i] = 0;
        }
        cout << array[i];
    } //End loop
}
```

Comment: Well, technically, you don't "call" a variable, but you "reference" or "use" it. Your `for` loop is checking `i != co` but the body of the `for` loop keeps changing `co` (with `co = co - 1` and the value of `i` is changing as your `for` loop update expression, so they chase each other but never reach the termination condition.

Comment: Not understanding the algorithm well, you may want to use `i < co` instead of `i != co`.

Comment: I'd suggest that you use the debugger to step through the code, with watch points set for `co` and `i`, so you can watch what's happening. There's no better tool for figuring out logic errors than the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

- You are incrementing `i` and decrementing `co` in one loop, so when `co` is odd `i != co` will always be true and the loop will run forever.
- You allocated zero elements to the array `array`, so you must not read nor write `array[i]`. Because only `array[i]` is used to access the array, it can be replaced with a simple variable.

For example, input `234` won't cause an infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int array; // replace array with simple variable (TODO: fix the name)
    int dec; //user input
    int v = 1; //other variable
    int co = 0; //This is the varaible i want to call

    cout << "Input here : ";
    cin >> dec;
    cout << "\n\n";

    while (v <= dec) {
        co++; //this were i assing the variable
        v = v * 2;
    }

    if (co % 2 != 0) { // infinite loop check
        cout << "the loop will run infinitely!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i != co; i++) { //this is where i have the problem, i cant call `co`
        co = co - 1;
        if (v <= dec) { //Binary will be 1
            dec = dec - v;
            v = v / 2;
            array = 1;
        }
        else { //Binary will be 0
            v = v / 2;
            array = 0;
        }
        cout << array;
    } //End loop
}
```

Comment: i need the for loop to run the number of time 'co' and the array needs to be intact
here is my full code https://repl.it/@Turtleman_42/Decimal-Converter-But-Better#main.cpp